# In "git checkout -- files", what does "--" mean?

Tags: git

Is it the "end of option" I am used to see in bash (and if yes, why do we use it) or is it a Git notation for the Index or the HEAD?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `--` separates the paths from the other options. From the [documentation](http://www.ru.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

```
git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...
```

If this notation didn't exist the following two commands would be ambiguous:

```
git checkout <tree-ish> <path1> <path2>
git checkout <path1> <path2> <path3>
```

With the `--` notation it is clear which is meant:

```
git checkout <tree-ish> -- <path1> <path2>
git checkout -- <path1> <path2> <path3>
```

The documentation I linked to above includes an [example](http://www.ru.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html#_examples) of when you might need it:

> $ git checkout hello.c
>
> If you have an unfortunate branch that is named hello.c, this step would be confused as an instruction to switch to that branch. You should instead write:
>
> $ git checkout -- hello.c

Comment: Of course, if you have a path called `-f`, that raises other questions, like why you need a path called `-f`. :)

Comment: @John Feminella: True, I found a hopefully better example.

Comment: The -- not only separates paths from options. You also need -- to separate that separator from a file called -- as in `git checkout -- --`.